# time series plot clustered over days

Tags: time-series, gnuplot

I am trying to plot aircraft methane observations which are averaged in minutes. When I tried to plot it in gnuplot, several data points are clustered vertically on the day (while the data is recorded in minutes). It means that the data is plotted in steps of days, not in minutes. I was not able to fix it. I attach the simple code I used.

```
set terminal png size 5000,3500 enhanced font 'arial,60'
set output 'series_1.png'
set datafile separator ","
set multiplot layout 2,1
set border 31 lw 4
set grid
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d/%H:%M"
set border lw 5
set xrange ["2014/09/01/00:01":"2014/11/30/00:01"]
set xtics "2014/09/01/00:01", 3600, "2014/11/30/00:01"
set yrange [1700:2500]

set format x "%d/%b/%y\n%H:%M"
set style line 2 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 ps 3.5 lc rgb "red"
set style line 3 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 ps 3.5 lc rgb "blue"

set size 0.8,0.6
set origin 0.1,0.2
set xlabel 'days'
set ylabel 'methane (ppb)'
plot 'data_fwd_alt.txt' using 1:($8*1e9) with linespoints ls 2 notitle
unset multiplot
```

My data looks like the following

```
2014/09/09/12:39,  26.56,  81.21,4254.11,1,000027,    1.95670000E-06,    1.89428172E-06,    6.24182808E-08
2014/09/09/12:40,  26.60,  81.24,4550.06,1,000028,    1.96390000E-06,    1.88243082E-06,    8.14691769E-08
2014/09/09/12:41,  26.65,  81.25,4728.63,1,000029,    1.94770000E-06,    1.86898377E-06,    7.87162278E-08
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you all in advance.
Janardanan

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: At least for the couple of data points you posted, this seem to be working fine for me. The range of your x-axis is 3 months, so data points that are only a minute apart will be very nearly on top of each other (or exactly on top of each other when you use a pixel-based terminal). In the output you posted you can actually see that even within a single "cluster" there is some horizontal variation of the data points. What happens when you "zoom in" by using a smaller xrange?

Comment: it also works fine for me. Could you maybe post more data (at least a few days)?

Comment: Thank you very much, user8153. Yes, since there are large data gaps within these three months some points are very close in the image. If i zoom I can see they are separated. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you theozh, for your time. I think I understood the problem now.